# node.js simple res.render times out

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2

We have a very simple node.js/express 4.0 app that at the moment contains a single default route:

```
/* GET home page */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var products = heelsProducts;
  res.products = products;
  res.render('index', {title: 'Shop SKINNYprice!', req: req, products: res.products, _csrf: req.csrfToken()});
});
```

This route runs fine when we access it on our local development machines (Fedora 19) and issuing a quick test like `$ curl http://localhost:3000` results in the index page html being return instantly.

However, when we deploy this code base to our AWS EC2 instance (default Linux AMI) and issue the same curl the process will hang for approximately 60 seconds before returning this error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/root/git/skinnypriceshop/code/shop/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:662:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/root/git/skinnypriceshop/code/shop/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:146:12)
    at fn (/root/git/skinnypriceshop/code/shop/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:896:10)
    at /root/git/skinnypriceshop/code/shop/node_modules/ejs-locals/index.js:134:7
    at Object.exports.renderFile (/root/git/skinnypriceshop/code/shop/node_modules/ejs-locals/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:318:3)
    at module.exports (/root/git/skinnypriceshop/code/shop/node_modules/ejs-locals/index.js:85:7)
    at /root/git/skinnypriceshop/code/shop/node_modules/ejs-locals/index.js:131:7
    at Object.exports.renderFile (/root/git/skinnypriceshop/code/shop/node_modules/ejs-locals/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:318:3)
    at View.module.exports [as engine] (/root/git/skinnypriceshop/code/shop/node_modules/ejs-locals/index.js:85:7)
```

Some online searching for this issue seems to indicate that some sort of subsequent response is being made which is also attempting to write to the header however nothing we have seen in our code seems to be a candidate for this.

Any ideas at this point would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any  custom middleware that would affect that route?

Comment: I think problem is you are using `res` object in `res.render` call just say `products` and remove the line `res.products = products`.

Comment: yzarubin - answer the question with your comment above and I'll mark it as accepted. In the end you were correct that there was an intervening piece of middleware (memcached) that was not started on the deployment server. Also Mritunjay you are correct about the res.products = products being extranious. Wasn't the source of the problem but wasn't helping either :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just marking this question as answered. Hat-tip to yzarubin's comment who ultimately led me to resolve issue which was that a piece of middleware on the server (memcached) was not started.